# How to practise fire worship in modern times?

Tags: vedas, rituals, yajna, vedic-rituals, agni

Is there a simple way to practise fire worship more suited to modern times and not too complex and time-taking?

Comment: Perhaps you can check out the practices followed by the Arya Samaj that are mostly simplified versions of Vedic practices. Arya Samaj also rejects the authority of the later scriptures like Purans and does not belive in idol worship.

Comment: Under ritual tag , achamanam procedure question is added.

Answer (score 0):

This is directly the procedure. There are other requirements of ritual purity for individual , apparel, ( bath) , cleanliness , events around ( death) and dates. Preliminary mantras. Will post on that later as another question.

Agnihotra:
Havan kund, cowdung cakes, whole rice akshat, ghee.( evacuate smoke/ fire alarm, and fire sprinkler off/ on)

A unauthenticated procedure of Agnihotra (is quoted as it is simple) from [Sanatan Santha Foundation writings](https://www.sanatan.org/en/a/88439.html)link traced by principal moderator

> 1. Direction : Sit facing the east
> 2. Method of kindling the fire
>    Keep a small, flat piece of cowdung cake at the bottom of the vessel,
>    and above it arrange cowdung cakes smeared with ghee in such a manner
>    (2-3 layers of vertically and horizontally arranged cowdung cakes)
>    that there is free flow of air within the spaces. Then, take a piece
>    of cowdung cake, apply a little ghee to it and after kindling it, keep
>    it in the Agnihotra vessel.
>    After some time, all the cowdung cakes will start burning. For
>    kindling the fire, you can use a hand-held fan. However, never blow
>    air from the mouth; else, germs from the mouth will enter the fire. Do
>    not use inflammable substances such as kerosene to kindle the fire,
>    since the fire should remain smokeless.
>
> 2B. Mantras to be recited At sunrise : 1. Sooryaya swáahá, Sooryáya
> idam na mama; 2. Prajápataye swáahá, Prajápatay idam na mama
>
> सूर्याय स्वाहा, सूर्याय इदं न मम । प्रजापतये स्वाहा, प्रजापतय इदं न मम
>
> At sunset : 1. Agnaye swaáhá, Agnay idam na mama; 2. Prajápataye
> swáahá, Prajápatay idam na mama
>
> अग्नये स्वाहा, अग्नय इदं न मम । प्रजापतये स्वाहा, प्रजापतय इदं न मम ॥
>
> 2C. Offering the oblation ingredients to Agni Take two pinches of rice
> grains on your palm or in a copper plate and add a few drops of cow’s
> ghee to it. Precisely at sunrise / sunset, recite the first mantra
> once and take the mixture of rice grains and ghee in the pinch (made
> by joining the middle finger, ring finger and thumb of the right
> hand). Offer the mixed ingredients (Rice grains sufficient to fill a
> pinch) to Agni while pronouncing ‘swáahá’.
> Again, offer the mixture of rice and ghee to Agni with the right hand
> when reciting the second mantra once while pronouncing the word
> ‘swáahá’.
> Benefits : this is yaagam, effort.

Arya samaj procedure link is given as actual procedure too long to quote here:
https://davchennai.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/%E2%80%A6

Comment: It seems that most part of the answer has been copied from a [webpage](https://www.sanatan.org/en/a/88439.html) Note that you should [cite proper references and give attributions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) while taking material from elsewhere. Also have a look at [what sources are considered valid](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/816/277)

Comment: Sir, reference link was included. Just need to click on it. It is underlined in blue showing it to be a link. 
  https://www.sanatan.org/en/a/88439.html

Comment: No it wasn't. Moderator had to include it

Comment: Sorry, for the error and sorry for lying , Lying knowing and unknowingly are wrong.

Comment: I have obtained a complete pdf of Vedic Agnihotra as pdf. Is there any facility to upload. Also this link worked for me https://davchennai.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Agnihotra-Book-Final.pdf.   is arya samaj procedure accepted ?

Comment: No, you can link it, include screenshots, etc., but there is no way to upload.

Comment: Ok. link is given - same link in comment and question.

Comment: Well, only gṛhastha dvijas have adhikāra of the anuṣṭhāna of agnihotra, I am not sure, if you know about that. If agnihotra is performed against vidhāna, the yajña is niṣphala simply and one commits pāpakarman too. Ārya Samāj claims to follow the Veda, yet spits on the śāstrīyavidhāna unfortunately. There are umpteen ways of doing upāsanā/pūjā of Agni, which are open to all, and in line with śāstrīya vidhāna and paramparā. Anuṣṭhāna of śrauta yajñas, is not the only way.

Comment: @Bingming interesting can you please elaborate more perhaps in a new answer? Of course, you don't have to, but I am genuinely interested.